# rollback not working in unit test junit 5

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, jdbc, junit

I have rolled back the changes made in a database, but the changes are being made in the database. Since it;s a unit test I can't have the data being tested inserted in the database.

I tried to add a member in db and got that member through his id by result set, but the member is being added in the db. I gave rollback to stop the changes made in db, but it's not working, I can see the member being added to db. Any solution?

```
@Test public void TestAddMember() { Member member = new Member();   
    try ( Connection connect = BookControl_jdbc.connection()) {
        try ( Statement stcheck = connect.createStatement()) {
            connect.setAutoCommit(false);
            //input parameters
            String name = "lia";
            int age = 20;
            String gender = "F";
            String status = "ACTIVE";
            member.setAge(age);
            member.setGender(gender);
# member.setName(name);
            member.setStatus(status);

            memberControl.addMember(member);
            memberControl.viewMembers();
            int memberId;
     
            String singleMemberQuery = "SELECT Member_id,Member_name,Age,Gender, Member_Status FROM Member WHERE Member_name='" + member.getName() + "';";
            ResultSet rs = MemberControlDao_jdbc.getStmtResultSet(singleMemberQuery);
            assertTrue(rs.next());
            memberId = rs.getInt("Member_id");
            assertEquals(name, rs.getString("Member_name"));
            assertEquals(age, rs.getInt("Age"));
            assertEquals(gender, rs.getString("Gender"));
            assertEquals(status, rs.getString("Member_Status"));
            
        } finally {
            connect.rollback();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use something like testcontainers-java for your unit tests. Are you by any chance using MyISAM tables? Also, please provide a [mre]. The code shown doesn't actually **insert** anything. Also, please learn how to use prepared statements. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You rollback the transaction on a particular connection. Perhaps `memberControl` doesn't use that connection, or `addMember` commits.

Comment: "I can see the member being added to db" What does this mean?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry for not giving enough clarity, I'm inserting the data in addMember method by passing an object. and thank you for your clarification. I'll look into prepared statements and testContainers.

Comment: @Danjr You don't **show** what that method does. Likely it creates its own connection and commits the data.

Comment: @tgdavies while testing i'm parallelly looking into database as well so I can see the member data I use for testing is getting added in that table in spite of rollback.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah